# ExtJS MVC conventions, naming and behavior

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Lately (2.x / 3.x) I just used xtype & factory methods to receive a instance of a class which was as simply as fast. Now I have started 4.x and my first App with MVC. As described in the tutorial the MVC pattern requires me to extend a class for each view I wan't to use, even if I use it just one time. But the best practice written by Sencha itself says:

> *just extend for re-useability or adding of functionality*

In my case I need to register a whole bunch of classes even if they could be created from one base class except of some params like `title, width,...`

Another point is that the Controller overwrites any StoreId by convention and also requires a strict typing, means the class-name must end with an `s`. But as far as I know I cannot spare neither the model nor the store within the the controller store/model-array so is there any other point for this convention cause it seems not to spare typing.

Next point is that after merging from 3.X to 4.X the application initial load time has extended which seems to be caused due to either the many new classes that need to get defined or due to the fact that all controllers get instantiated at startup due to the default behavior of the MVC pattern. Is there any way to not auto instantiate a controller and just doing it lazy, for example when I request it on the application controller?

Yes I know, that are a bunch of questions but I guess they all around the same topic.

***EDIT***

> After some sourcecode-digging I am no longer sure about the
>   requirement of the `s` when naming a store. I thought I stumbled over
>   this while going through the MVC tutorial. Can anyone verify this?

***EDIT 2***

*My conclusions*

Lacy rendering is quite simple. First of all the Controller should not be mentioned in the ApplicationController controller array. To create a instance of such a controller use the `ApplicationController.getController(pureClassName)` 
[*Note that each controller contains a reference to the ApplicationController called* `application`] Now you need to be aware of the fact that the `init(application)` method and the `onLaunch(application)` method get no longer invoked by the ApplicationController, you need to do this yourself. When calling `getController()` the ApplicationController first lookup if there is already a instance of this controller in the internal reference cache if not it creates a instance and inject the controllername as `Id`. So controllers are a sort of singleton which is perfectly fine.
The controller itself creates all the getter for the registered stores, models and views and, that's a guess, it instantiate them (at least the stores)
About naming restrictions for stores, there no restrictions about ending with an s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are very valid points.

First, it has to be mentioned that you don't have to use MVC with ExtJS 4. You can still use ExtJS 3 style in your code.

I assume that if you understand the advantages of MVC and decide to adapt it, then yes - you will have to extend classes and there is some overhead, but admittedly you will end up with a cleaner, more reusable code. It has to be said that while you need to extend top-level views, the items within them can still be coded old style. In addition to this, within the init() of the controller you can modify certain view configs (which allows less of class extension, but more controller code).

I have to admit that if you have experience with ExtJS 3 and you're migrating to MVC style of an app, you will eventually see that the benefits outweigh the work involved.

Personally it's the first time I've been made aware of this 's' business with stores. So I can't comment much on this.

Lastly, a properly-written ExtJs 4 app, one that makes use of dynamic loading should load faster than an ExtJS 3 app. You can also compile an Ext version that only includes code used  in your app. And yes, you can instantiate controllers (and their views and stores) when you need them, which works like a charm:

```
loadPage: function(aControllerName)
{
    // save recent page in a cookie
    Ext.util.Cookies.set('RecentPage', aControllerName);

    // Dynamically load the controller
    var iController = this.getController(aControllerName);

    // Manually initialise it
    iController.init();

    // Load the page (by getting the first view of the controller).
    var iPage = this.getView(iController.views[0]).create();

    // Add the page to the content panel.
    var iContentPanel = this.getContentPanel();

    iContentPanel.removeAll(true);

    iContentPanel.add(iPage);

    iContentPanel.doLayout();
}
```

Comment: OK, if I understand you right (and after a deeper look into the application controller source) I may spare the controller name in the application controller array and simply init it myself lazily. Based on my design I would call `onLaunch` instead of `init`. I guess I can do the same with each view & store, even if I loose the autoconstructed methods in that case? Without testing it `this.getView(iController.views[0])` should return a classinstance or am I wrong? All in all your answer brings me a good part forward +1

Comment: The other side is that the ExtJS app is just a part of a framework and get's packed up. I don't use the dynamic loading at this time and I must say that I am not a friend of it, except for debugging purposes.

Comment: OK. I see where you are going with this (given point 1 in the original question). Although I haven't tried it myself, my answer to your first comment is yes and yes. What you propose should work. Although I have a feeling we're missing something if this is the solution we came up with. I need to look deeper into this, but will only be able to do so tomorrow...

Comment: And now that I had a few minutes to think about it... I make a very rough assumption that what you are trying to achieve is similar to an email client where every click on an email will open a new view with that email? But you still want a single controller class to control the similar views? If this is the case you can run into troubles as I believe getController will return the same instance and not a new one. If such is the case, perhaps you are better off with Ext.create and handle the instances yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your really constructive help on this topic which lead me to the right way. No, I don't have a sort of mailprogramm but I have a huge amount of entities where most of them have their own controller (stores,models,views) I have edited my question to add my conclusion on this topic. And I can say that I am happy with this solution. For the overhead on the views; I simply have gone a step back and don't register all them so I can stay with my factory methods there.

Answer (score 1):

1.Izhaki answered your question well about the lazy controller initialization.

2.I am not really following you on the gripe about Store names. There are no restrictions on store names. They are merely suggestions of naming conventions.

3.The Ext.define method is great to define your classes  - similar to Java or other OO languages. This is NOT required however and you can simply use Ext.create method to create an instance of a framework component and pass it custom config object. 
You can also use Ext.define to create you base class and then call `Ext.create('MyBaseClass',{title:'mynew tile'});`  to get a slightly modified version of your base class.

I encourage you to read through the Sencha guides on [MVC](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture), and [Class system](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/class_system) and also review their examples to get better understanding.

Comment: -1 for your uncontructive answer. Read the question and the comments before writing a answer. Don't tell me about how great their class system is, I never have asked for that. I talked about overhead. I also have mentioned that I've been through the tutorial. Last; At no time I have critized @Izhaki answer and so far it is the best, but it is up to me to decide when my question is answered and who give the best answer. I am sorry but for me it smells you are in any way involved in the company

Comment: -1 for unconstructive comment LOL :) . 1. I never criticized @Izhaki answer, in fact I complimented it, see my answer. 2. Thank you for your compliment of associating me to Sencha, although that's not true. 3. I answered your direct questions about naming conventions and object extensions which flows directly from the Class system. 4. If you don't like my answer feel free to ignore it, there is no need to be disrespectful.